# Ругается на this при статике

Tags: php, ооп

Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

Не понимаю, в чём причина?

на  `getParam('a')` не ругается

а на `getAllSegments()` почему-то ругается

**index.php**

```
use library\Url;

var_dump(Url::getParam('a'));
var_dump(Url::getAllSegments());
```

**Url.php**

```
class Url {
    private $_url;
    private $_segments;
    private $_params;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $this->getSegmentsFormUrl();
        $this->_params = $_GET;
        unset($this->_params['url']);
    }

    protected static function getSegmentsFormUrl() {
        $segments = explode('/', $_GET['url']);

         if(empty($segments[count($segments)-1])) {
             unset($segments[count($segments)-1]);
         }

        return $segments;
    }

    public static function getParam($paramName) {
        return addslashes($_GET[$paramName]);
    }

    public static function getAllSegments() {
         return $this->_segments;
    }

}
```

Comment: чтобы понять в чем причина, нужно знать в чем разницы static от не static. всё! (http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.static.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this` указывает на текущий контекст. В контексте объекта - указывает на текущий скоуп. Так же работает абсолютно во всех языках программирования.

Поправка (PHP 5): `$this` в статических методах использовать нельзя
можно заменять на `self` и `static` - но только обращаясь к статическим полям и методам.
!!! При этом они указывают на разный контекст - смотрите примеры ниже !!!

#### Например:

```
class A{
    public static $a = 1;

    public static function getA(){
      return self::$a;
    }
 }

class B extends A{
   public static $a = 10;

}

echo B::getA();
```

Выведет 1
Здесь в `A::getA()` 'self' указывает на контекст A - те вот так вы и хотели как я понимаю.

#### Еще пример:

```
class A{
    public static $a = 1;

    public static function getA(){
      return static::$a;
    }
 }

class B extends A{
   public static $a = 10;

}

echo B::getA();
```

Этот пример выведет 10 - тк в `A::getA()` 'static' будет указывать на контекст вызова - те на B.
В обьекте B a = 10

#### Пример с `$this` (все нестатическое):

```
class A{
    public $a = 1;

    public function getA(){
      return $this->a;
    }
 }

class B extends A{
   public $a = 10;

}

$obj = new B();

echo $obj->getA();
```

Выведет 10
Тк `$this` в `$obj->getA()` указывает на текущий контекст исполнения (как и в JavaScript) - а контекст испольнения в данном случае скоуп экземпляра обьекта B.
А в нем a = 10

Comment: то есть как и в javascript?

Comment: Да - так же, только в статических методах this нельзя использовать. Но если бы они били не статические - то this бы указывало на текущий контекст исполнения. Как и в javascript. В php - в статических методах можно использовать self и static - я показал в чем разница в примерах. (Извиняюсь что переписывал несколько раз - сейчас все правильно - я запустил и проверил)

Comment: Я добавлю пример с this

Answer (score 2):

Всё просто. У тебя функция `getAllSegments()` статическая, а в статических функциях использовать `this` нельзя. `this` указывает на класс, который является "отцом" твоей функции, но статические функции не имеют, так сказать, класса-"родителя". Следовательно, `this` ни на что не указывает.

Создай экземляр класса и пользуйся им, убрав `static` у `getAllSegments()`, или сделай `segments`статической и убери `$this->`.